# Scripting variable to environment variable and vice versa

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

Can we pass values of scripting variables to environment variables when we are witing codes in sqlcmd scripts or batch scripts and vice versa ?

Answer (score 2):

**Using batch variables in sqlcmd**

a) Directly placing them in the command line. The cmd parser will expand the variables to the value as it is written in the line

```
set "lastName=Smith"
sqlcmd -Q "SELECT * From myTable Where LastName='%lastName%'"
```

b) Using declared variables in the sql query, and using the previous method to declare them in the sqlcmd command. If we have a `query.sql` filename containing

```
SELECT * From myTable Where LastName='$(LastName)'
```

Then it is possible to do the following call

```
set "lastName=Smith"
sqlcmd -i query.sql -v LastName="%lastName%"
```

**Using output of sqlcmd in batch files**

a) Send the output to a file (`-o` switch in sqlcmd) and then process it. See `for /?`

```
sqlcmd -i query.sql -o data.txt -h -1 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (data.txt) do ....
```

b) Directly process the output of the command. Again with `for /f` command.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('sqlcmd -i query.sql -h -1') do ....
```

In both cases, if what is needed is to assign value to a batch variable, you will have something like

```
for /f "... options ..." %%a in ('sqlcmd -i query.sql -h -1') do (
    ....
    set "varname=%%a"
    ....
)
```

processing the output/file and assigning the data to the variables.