# Variable defined in SQL readable by .cmd (pass a variable from SQL to cmd)

Tags: sql-server, variables, batch-file, cmd

I know how to setup a variable in a cmd file that passes the variable to SQL via sqlcmd.

Example:

```
sqlcmd -Usa -Ppass -d MASTER -v num="%num%" -i C:\scriptfile
```

My question is how can I define a variable in SQL that can be read outside of SQL. I know how to declare and define @variables in a SQL script but those are not recognized outside of when the SQL script runs.

My question is how to you pass a variable from SQL back to cmd?

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22711221/2861476) can help. At the end you need to output the value in the sqlcmd call for the batch file to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using scripting variable and using the `-v` option of `SQLCMD` utility. A small example from  [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx)

Consider that the script file name is `testscript.sql`, `Col1` is a scripting variable; your SQL script look like

```
USE test;

SELECT x.$(Col1) FROM Student x WHERE marks < 5;
```

You can then specify the name of the column that you want returned by using the `-v` option like

```
sqlcmd -v Col1 = "FirstName" -i c:\testscript.sql
```

Which will resemble to below query

```
SELECT x.FirstName FROM Student x WHERE marks < 5;
```

**EDIT:**

If you just want to capture the output from your script file then you can use `-o` parameter and specify a outfile like

```
sqlcmd -v Col1 = "FirstName" -i c:\testscript.sql -o output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. Your example is passing the variable from cmd to sql. My question is how to you pass a variable from SQL to cmd?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rahul, you inadvertently answered my question. You can output your script results to a file via the -o option for SQLCMD.

Thinking about that I realized I could use the PRINT SQL to create a -o .cmd file that contains the .cmd syntax to define a variable. Then in the .cmd file I tell it to run the SQL created .cmd file and then the variable gets defined in the .cmd environment.

Kind of a round about way but works!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just run a simple select to get your value or an exec spname that returns just the value you are after, you can use the following.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('sqlcmd -Usa -Ppass -W -h -1 -d MASTER -Q "select Column from table"') do set ResultVariable=%a
```

Remember to use %%a if putting this in a bat file